# Creating View with parameter [SQL,Pentaho Report Designer]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view, pentaho-report-designer

I have a SQL Query that accepts parameters for filtering report 
(${p_year, ${p_month}, ${p_comp}) in Pentaho Report Designer.

[In Pentaho Report Designer before using view]

```
SELECT INSERT_DATE,EXT,DURATION_S
FROM TABLE1
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),INSERT_DATE,112) = CONCAT(${p_year}, ${p_month}) 
AND DIRECTION = 'OUT'
AND EXT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE2.EXT
FROM TABLE2
WHERE ((COMP = ${p_comp} OR 'ALL' = ${p_comp}))
)
```

I am trying to create the view to include that query in SQL Server. However, I am not sure this is a correct view or not.
[In SQL Server]

```
CREATE VIEW CALLING AS
SELECT  INSERT_DATE,EXT,DURATION_S
FROM  TABLE1
WHERE DIRECTION = 'OUT' AND EXT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE2.EXT
FROM TABLE2
)
```

After that in Report Designer, I change the code to

```
select * from CALLING
```

However, I don't know how to add parameter (${p_year}, ${p_month}, ${p_comp}) into the new code. Any idea please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current view seems to correct for me but use `JOIN` inside the `VIEW`

```
CREATE VIEW Calling
AS
   SELECT  
          t1.INSERT_DATE, t2.EXT, t1.DURATION_S, t2.COMP  
   FROM  table1 t1
   INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.EXT = t1.EXT
   WHERE t1.DIRECTION = 'OUT'
```

And, you would require to call the view with `WHERE`clause

```
SELECT * FROM Calling
WHERE INSERT_DATE = @parameter AND COMP = @parameter
```

Or, you would also go with stored procedure where you could pass multiple parameters

Comment: Thanks, but how about parameter in subquery. SELECT DISTINCT TABLE2.EXT FROM TABLE2 WHERE ((COMP = ${p_comp} OR 'ALL' = ${p_comp})) . I mean how can I where it from the view?

Comment: @SNPalita... In order to filter the record based on what you have wrote you would require to include `COMP` column in `Calling` view. see my edit.